# How to convert GeoJSON to vector.pbf (Protobuf)?

Tags: type-conversion, protocol-buffers, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mbtiles

I have a big GeoJson file and I need to convert it to the vector format that can be loaded by the Mapbox. I need to have an external file, so I can't use Mapbox Studio for uploading and converting the data.

Currently I found https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe tool, but it converts GEoJSON to MBTiles (SQLite format). I think a can't use it for my map. As I can see from all the examples of the Mapbox service - it uses a XXX.vector.pbf (protobuf) format (small and fast). So the question is - how to get a Protobuf vector file from the original GeoJSON ? Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Tippecanoe is probably the right answer: it generates a ton of .pbf files, and bundles them into a single .mbtiles file. Usually you then pass that .mbtiles file to a vector tile server (there are [heaps](https://github.com/mapbox/awesome-vector-tiles#servers)), or upload it to Mapbox or something.

If you want to explode out the .mbtiles file, you can use [mbutil](https://github.com/mapbox/mbutil).

Finally, if you want to translate GeoJSON directly into protobuf format (different from the Mapbox vector tile format, I think), you can use [GeoBuf](https://github.com/mapbox/geobuf).